# how to declare a global variable within a for loop and why is the else statement read as unexpected?

Tags: r

I have datasets that have sulfate and nitrate columns in them. Depending on what the user chooses, either sulfate mean or nitrate mean is returned. I have a for loop and within it I have an IF and ELSE statement to sort this out. The following error arises when attempting to compile data.frame(datada,vec1):

"Error in data.frame(datada, vec1) : object 'datada' not found"

Also, the else statement is considered unexpected. The following error is given:

"Error: unexpected 'else' in " else"

```
complete <- function(directory,pollutant = "sulfate", id = 1:332) {

  datada <- id
  filelist <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)

  vec <- numeric() 
  vec1 <- numeric()
  vec2 <- numeric()

  for(i in datada) {

    if (pollutant == "sulfate"){
      data <- read.csv(filelist[i])
      vec1<- c(vec1, colMeans(data$sulfate,na.rm = TRUE )

    }  
    data.frame(datada,vec1)                  #datada is not "found"

    else (pollutant == "nitrate"){              #else is "unexpected"
        data <- read.csv(filelist[i])
        vec2<- c(vec2, colMeans(data$sulfate,na.rm = TRUE )

      }  
      data.frame(datada,vec2)
  }
```

Here is what one dataset looks like:

```
          Date sulfate nitrate ID
1   2001-01-01      NA      NA  2
2   2001-01-02      NA      NA  2
3   2001-01-03      NA      NA  2
4   2001-01-04      NA      NA  2
5   2001-01-05      NA      NA  2
6   2001-01-06      NA      NA  2
7   2001-01-07      NA      NA  2
8   2001-01-08      NA      NA  2
9   2001-01-09      NA      NA  2
10  2001-01-10      NA      NA  2
11  2001-01-11      NA      NA  2
12  2001-01-12      NA      NA  2
13  2001-01-13      NA      NA  2
14  2001-01-14      NA      NA  2
15  2001-01-15      NA      NA  2
16  2001-01-16      NA      NA  2
17  2001-01-17      NA      NA  2
18  2001-01-18      NA      NA  2
19  2001-01-19    2.30   0.699  2
20  2001-01-20      NA      NA  2
21  2001-01-21      NA      NA  2
22  2001-01-22      NA      NA  2
23  2001-01-23      NA      NA  2
24  2001-01-24      NA      NA  2
25  2001-01-25    2.19   4.970  2
```

Its expected to return something like this:

```
  datada vec
1      1 117
2      3 243
3      5 402
4      7 442
5      9 275
```

Generated by the data.frame(datada,vec1)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to manipulate environment objects, the easiest thing to do is to declare your variable outside the function and use `<<-` form of assignment inside the function.

```
datada <- NULL
...
complete <- function(directory,pollutant = "sulfate", id = 1:332) {
    datada <<- id
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why `datada` is not found - when I tried a simplified version of the function on my system it seems to work fine.

As to the else -- an `else` must come directly after the end of the `if`'s statement. It's not expected because you placed `data.frame(datada,vec1)` before it. If you put that line into the `{}`, everything should be fine.

But generally speaking your code is unnecessarily complex, plus it doesn't actually return anything.

Try something like this:

```
complete <- function(directory,pollutant = "sulfate", id = 1:332) {
  datada <- id
  filelist <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
  if (!(pollutant) %in% c("sulfate","nitrate")) stop("Unknown pollutant")
  lapply(filelist, function(x) {
    data<-read.csv(x)
    colMeans(data[,pollutant],na.rm=TRUE)
  })
}
```

This will output a list where each element is the vector of colMeans of each of the files. You could replace lapply with `sapply` which will (probably) give you a matrix instead of a list.

(note I couldn't test it because I don't have the dataset, so there may be some errors here)

Comment: Please have a look at the expected output with data.frame(datada, vec1). That is the return value.